# Set Google Calendar Event Description with AddOn

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, add-on

### Goal

Im working on building a Google Calendar modify the description of a Google Calendar Event.

### Problem

I do not see how to edit the event description. I followed [this](https://nsulistiyawan.github.io/building-google-calendar-add-ons-1.html) tutorial to start building the AddOn.

I also found [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/calendar-event-action-response) documentation that shows how to edit the attendees, but I have not been able to figure out how to edit the description of an event from within an AddOn.

### Added info

#### Visual representation of the goal

[image]

#### Output from [`eventUpdateTrigger`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/calendar-addons#Calendar.FIELDS.homepageTrigger)

The below object shows that the `eventId` is not given to the `eventUpdateTrigger` callback

```
    "hostApp": "calendar",
    "commonEventObject": {
        "platform": "WEB",
        "hostApp": "CALENDAR"
    },
    "calendar": {
        "organizer": {
            "email": "<email>"
        },
        "capabilities": {
            "canSetConferenceData": true,
            "canAddAttendees": true,
            "canSeeConferenceData": true,
            "canSeeAttendees": true
        },
        "calendarId": "jamesdouitsis@gmail.com",
        "id": "<id>"
    },
    "clientPlatform": "web"
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code that is creating the Calendar event in the first place?

Comment: There is no code to create the event. I create it manually and then I want the side bar (addon) to be able to auto add certain things to the description for me

Answer (score 0):

#### What's wrong with using setDescription and setTitle

```
function saveDescriptionAndTitle(obj) {
  let cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(obj.calid);
  let ev = cal.getEventById(obj.evid);
  ev.setTitle(obj.title);
  ev.setDescription(obj.desc);
}
```

Comment: How would this work for a new Event? The `cal.getEventById(...)` wouldn't be able to pickup a new event

Comment: What's the difference between editing a new or old event.  I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: If the event hasn't been created, there will be no `eventId` to look up. I did try it and I only get access to the `calendarId`, no `eventId`

Comment: If the event has not been created then it's not a Google Calendar Event and your question doesn't apply to it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I Have updated the question title. So the issue is when creating an event I am unable to programatically set the description.

Comment: What is the origin of the description?  Who or what will be creating the event?

Comment: I don't understand why this doesn't solve your issue, `setDescription` is exactly the method you need to do this @jdouitsis

Comment: I have added some additional information to hopefully clarify the goal

Answer (score 0):

For this, you will need to be required to call google APIs there is no method to directly update the event description without an API

API Ref. - https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/update

In AppScript there  1 class that you can use to call that API
might be that helps you

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app?hl=en#setdescriptiondescription

Comment: Not really.  In a coment under my answer the op states `the issue is when creating an event I am unable to programatically set the description`.  The OP is talking about set the the description programmatically prior to event creation.  It's still not clear to me what the OP actually means by that.   My guess is that it has something to do with the User  Interface.

Comment: I have added some extra information to hopefully clarify what I am attempting to do